# Calculating variance for a window of samples which already contains pre-calculated variances

Tags: statistics, algorithms, variance

In a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116344/317350), the following solution was given for calculating the variance from a stream of sample values (from Knuth via [John D. Cook](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/)):

$$
\begin{align*}
m_k&=m_{k-1}+\frac{x_k-m_{k-1}}k \\
v_k&=v_{k-1}+(x_k-m_{k-1})(x_k-m_k)
\end{align*}
$$

with variance $$\sigma^2=\frac{v_k}{k-1}$$

If we kept track of $m_k$, $v_k$, and $\sigma^2$ for each sample, then could we easily compute the variance for a given *window* of samples between $i$ and $i+j$ with a simple manipulation of those saved values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an answer can be found here: http://jonisalonen.com/2014/efficient-and-accurate-rolling-standard-deviation/

If the window is moving from $$(x_0,...,x_N-_1)$$ to $$(x_1,...,x_N)$$ then:

[image]

[image]